# Que tipo de codigo tendria que poner para que queden iguales?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

soy un NOVATO en esto del Diseño Web , y por eso los quería molestar porque tengo un problema en mi linea de codigo la cual es que cuando escribo la misma linea de codigo en Visual a mi me aparece difetente IMAGEN 2 , hace que cada imagen quede con el texto pegado y no queda como muestra la imagen 1[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecSAo.png)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ocupamos agregues tu código por favor y expliques mejor tu duda, checa [ask]

Comment: Hola ,como lo dije antes soy nuevo en esto y bueno también en este tipo de foros y blogs, el problema es que tengo el mismo codigo que mi profesor pero al ejecutar queda diferente.

Comment: En este momento no puedo ingresar el contenido de dicho problema , con respecto a la pregunta de que si puedo ayudar en una solución como esta , no lo creo porque en verdad soy muy nuevo y no se mucho, por eso estaba buscando la ayuda de ustedes gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy difícil saber cuál es tu problema, pero en base a mi experiencia deberías revisar lo siguiente:

1. Si trabajas con archivos separados .html y .css, verifica que el archivo css este importado en el html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

2. Verifica los selectores de tu css, puede que no este bien escritos o no los tengas aplicados correctamente en las etiquetas html.

```css
span { font-size: 12px; }
.red { color: red; }
#bold { font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<body>
    <span class="red" id="bold">Hola</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Se te agradece el interés de ayudar pero lo ideal en este caso es esperar a que el OP muestre que lleva, de esa manera podemos ser mas certeros, ya que no sabemos por ejemplo si esas son las etiquetas y estilos que usa o debe usar

Comment: Despues de tanta vuelta pude resolver por fin el problema, era por una sola letra el problema , tenia un <articl/> mal escrito y por eso no me hacia los cambios.

Comment: Es de los errores más comunes cuando pasa eso: etiquetas, clases o ids mal escritas o estilos no importados. Lo he visto mucho en gente que va empezando y aún no se acostumbra, incluso hasta en gente con experiencia y que tiene horas buscando el problema. Siempre hay que ver como lo escribes.